# How to set value to lambda if this function do not call

Tags: c#, lambda, properties

My code is similar to this:

```
 public decimal Count { get; set; } 
 public decimal PriceWithoutVat { get; set; }
 public decimal AmountWithoutVat => Count * PriceWithoutVat;
```

but I want `AmountWithoutVat` to be settable so that:

- If I don't set `AmountWithoutVat`, `AmountWithoutVat` is `Count * PriceWithoutVat`
- If I set `AmountWithoutVat` then the new value is stored and used.

Comment: if I am not mistaken, that's a read-only property.

Comment: *AmmountWithoutVat* One m, *Amount* :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't do it (at least for a property with => syntax alone as it's readonly)

You could add a nullable local field and use null-coalescing operator to return something else if it's null:

```
private decimal? _ammountWithoutVat;

public decimal AmmountWithoutVat 
{ 
   get => _ammountWithoutVat ?? Count * PriceWithoutVat;
   set => _ammountWithoutVat = value;
}
```

P.S.

As Tim Schmelter has kindly pointed out:
"Property set statements are a C#7 feature"

In older versions of C# you could use:

```
public decimal AmmountWithoutVat 
{ 
    get { return _ammountWithoutVat ?? Count * PriceWithoutVat; }
    set { _ammountWithoutVat = value; }
}
```

Comment: You should probably add a method "`void ResetAmountWithoutVat()`", otherwise you can't return to the `_ammountWithoutVat = null` case after setting `AmmountWithoutVat `...

Comment: You might want to note that [property set statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#property-set-statements) are a C#7 feature

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using `c#7`, you can do it "old" way:

```
private decimal? amountWithoutVat;
public decimal AmountWithoutVat
{
    get { return amountWithoutVat ?? Count * PriceWithoutVat; }
    set { amountWithoutVat = value; }
}
```